# WPF Datagrid TemplateColumn Control Enable and Disable

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have Datagrid with two TemplateColumn.

First column is a Combobox and Second column with Extended IntergerUpDown control

I need to Enable/Disable the IntegerUpDown control based on the Combox box SelectedItem value.

Please help me how to accomplish this. Sample xaml below.

```
<Grid><DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List1}" Name="x1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ColorTemplate">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.List2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"  SelectedValue="{Binding ColourId}" SelectedValuePath="Id" Tag="{Binding Id}"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="discussTemplate" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                         />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="UPDown" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <extToolkit:IntegerUpDown AllowSpin="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Minimum="0"
                                                  x:Name="updown"
                                                  IsEnabled="????" >

                            </extToolkit:IntegerUpDown>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with a DataTrigger on your ViewModel ColourId property.

As your SelectedValue property on the ComboBox is already binded, you can have a DataTrigger on your extToolkit:IntegerUpDown control that will set IsEnabled to True/False based on ColourId value on your ViewModel.